# Display groups of columns in wide table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have developed a table with very wide columns and want to selectively view sets of the columns, as a user clicks a series of links.

[This JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisGuest/9pv4v9jd/) shows what I have attempted so far.

This uses jQquery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` over a rendered HTML table. Having to render HTML with all these class values on each column is a bit of a nightmare when dealing with existing MVC frameworks.

I suspect that there are simple and more attractive ways to do this with a custom jQquery plug in, that loads the data as JSON. Could someone suggest a simpler solution to what I am now doing?

Comment: Have a look at datatables.net - it's a great tool for handling table data

Comment: I'd looked initially there, but hadn't spotted anything. Perhaps you want to suggest this as a solution: http://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reinventing wheels with tables, I'd take a look at the excellent jQuery plug-in [datatables](http://datatables.net) - it can handle almost any table data query you've thought of and offer some you might not have.

Comment: Here is my new JSFiddle based on your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisGuest/orgj7oL9/10/